# How do I select inside mysql database where one of the column receives json data

Tags: mysql

I have a table where in one of the column gets json data. `json_data: {"pImageCount":"4","pSellerType":"xxx",....`

I want to `select * from tableName where ....`
How do I say pImageCount ='4'?

Comment: `select * from tableName where json_data like '%"pImageCount":"4"%'`

Comment: Could you not store decoded data instead? From MySQL's point of view, it would be much more 'useful'

Answer (score 2):

MySQL does not have built in JSON parsing, but you can install the [JSON UDFs](http://labs.mysql.com/) and do this:

```
select * 
from tableName 
where json_extract(json_data,'pImageCount') = '4'
```

Or you can install [common_schema](http://code.google.com/p/common-schema/) and do this:

```
select * 
from tableName 
where common_schema.extract_json_value(json_data,'pImageCount') = '4'
```

Both approaches will require a full table scan, so they may not be fast enough if the data volume is large and you require low query latency. In that case you may want to modify the schema in order to index the data.

Here are some blog posts I've written about JSON parsing in MySQL. They are more geared towards parsing values out of specific rows identified by other criteria, but with small data volumes you can use them for filtering as demonstrated above:

http://mechanics.flite.com/blog/2014/02/14/faster-json-parsing-using-mysql-json-udfs/
http://mechanics.flite.com/blog/2013/04/08/json-parsing-in-mysql-using-common-schema/